# Filling shape with labels or attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, style, fields-attributes, fill

In QGIS, I would like to set the fill of a shape to be a pattern repetition of label values (i.e. an attribute of the item).

Is this possible, looking a little like the sketch below (for shapes with `ID = 1,2,3`)?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On `Layer Properties` window, select `Single Symbol | Fill | Simple fill - Symbol Layer Type- Point pattern fill | Font marker`. Then click `Data defined override (field)` and choose your field.

[image]