# Layer styling: custom text as a polygon fill in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, style, fill

How would one fill a polygon with a custom text? I know you can use [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227557/filling-shape-with-labels-or-attributes-in-qgis) approach to create a label-wise polygon filling (= labeling polygon with their attribute's values), but is there an option to just specify a simple text (not a simple character!) as an filling attribute?

This is the desired result for the polygons with the the example text "Example":

[image]

Comment: should this be always the same text for every polygon in this layer? or is it a text string from the attributes?

Comment: The same text for every polygon.  See the example image in the updated OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method outlined in the question that you linked to but instead of specifiying an attribute just use a string in the data defined properties of the font marker.  You will need to adjust the font marker spacing and font size to suit.

[image: point pattern fill with font marker]

Comment: Tried that, but with string in double quotes, so it didn't work, and I gave up too quickly! Thanks! #facepalm

Comment: [mixedbredie](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8977/mixedbredie), but how it is possible to minimize the number of signatures up to one, to be able to put a single layer name in the middle of the polygon? Many thanks!